# How to reload/update UITableView after resizing a cell containing web view dynamically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiwebview, autolayout, uiwebviewdelegate

I have few sections in table view. One section has only one cell containing a UIWebView. When it got loaded with html, I update cell with correct height as follows:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    var frame = webView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame = frame
    var fittingSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    fittingSize = fittingSize.height > CGFloat(100) ? fittingSize : CGSize(width: fittingSize.width, height: CGFloat(100))
    frame.size = fittingSize
    webView.frame = frame

    let cellSize = fittingSize.height;
    print(cellSize)

    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, fittingSize.width + 7, fittingSize.height + 7)

    parent?.reloadTable()
}
```

In Parent,

```
func reloadTable() {

    //let t = self.numberOfSectionsInTableView(self.tableView)

    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    //self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 4), withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

There is an another section under the cell. I tried several ways to update body cell. It got updated but following section header doesn't got moved below with body cells adjusted height.

Now any suggestion please?
Thanks